# .Net for Apache Spark error from DataFrame.Show after UDF called

Tags: c#, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-dotnet

I'm a long time C# programmer but just getting my feet wet with .Net for Apache Spark.
Following many "getting started" instructions and videos, I installed:

- 7-Zip
- Java 8
- I downloaded Apache Spark from https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html
- .NET for Apache Spark v2.1.1
- WinUtils.exe
  I'm running this on Window 10

**Problem:**  When I call DataFrame.Show() after doing a DataFrame.WithColumn() using a UDF, I always get an error:
[2023-02-07T15:45:31.3903664Z] [DESKTOP-H37P8Q0] [Error] [TaskRunner] [0] ProcessStream() failed with exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: type

TestCases.csv looks like this:

```
+----+----+----+----+
|name|posX|posY|rate|
+----+----+----+----+
|   A| 100| -20|  20|
|   B| 400|  30|  45|
|   C| -10|  75|  61|
|   D| 100| 120|  76|
|   E|  48|  96|  88|
|   F| 808|  46|  55|
|   G|1200|  91|  99|
+----+----+----+----+
```

OrderList.csv looks like this, but it has 5040 rows:

```
+-------------+
|        names|
+-------------+
|A|B|C|D|E|F|G|
|A|B|C|D|E|G|F|
|A|B|C|D|F|E|G|
|A|B|C|D|F|G|E|
|A|B|C|D|G|E|F|
|A|B|C|D|G|F|E|
|A|B|C|E|D|F|G|
|A|B|C|E|D|G|F|
|A|B|C|E|F|D|G|
|A|B|C|E|F|G|D|
|A|B|C|E|G|D|F|
|A|B|C|E|G|F|D|
|A|B|C|F|D|E|G|
|A|B|C|F|D|G|E|
|A|B|C|F|E|D|G|
|A|B|C|F|E|G|D|
|A|B|C|F|G|D|E|
|A|B|C|F|G|E|D|
|A|B|C|G|D|E|F|
|A|B|C|G|D|F|E|
+-------------+
```

Here is the Main() function:

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create Spark session
            SparkSession spark =
                SparkSession
                    .Builder()
                    .AppName("test_Spark_app")
                    .GetOrCreate();

            // We don't want to see all those INFO messages
            spark.SparkContext.SetLogLevel("WARN");

            // Create initial DataFrame
            DataFrame dataFrame = spark
                .Read()
                .Schema("name STRING, posX INT, posY INT, rate INT")
                .Csv(@"C:\TestSparkApp\bin\Debug\net6.0\TestCases.csv");

            // print out the data
            dataFrame.Show();

            GetOrders();

            // Create orders DataFrame
            DataFrame ordersFrame = spark
                .Read()
                .Schema("names STRING")
                .Csv(@"C:\TestSparkApp\bin\Debug\net6.0\OrderList.csv");

            // print out the data
            ordersFrame.Show();

            // add all the players to each row
            string playersAsString = Collector.PlayersToString(_players);
            ordersFrame = ordersFrame.WithColumn("players", Lit(playersAsString));

            // print out the data
            ordersFrame.Show();

            // user defined function
            Func<Column, Column, Column> GetSubst = Udf<string, string, int>(
                (strOrder, strPlayers) =>
                {
                    return GetSubstance(strOrder, strPlayers);
                });

            // call the user defined function and add a new column to the dataframe
            ordersFrame = ordersFrame.WithColumn("substance", GetSubst(ordersFrame["names"], ordersFrame["players"]).Cast("Integer"));
            
            // if I comment out the following, it does NOT produce the error:
            // print out the data
            ordersFrame.Show(20,20,false);

            // Stop Spark session
            spark.Stop();
        }
```

Here is the UDF function:

```
        public static int GetSubstance(string strOrder, string strPlayers)
        {
            // to simplify things, we are just returning zero
            return 0;
        }
```

Here is the output:

```
> C:\TestSparkApp>spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.deploy.dotnet.DotnetRunner --master local bin\Debug\net6.0\microsoft-spark-2-4_2.11-2.1.1.jar dotnet bin\Debug\net6.0\TestSparkApp.dll
> 23/02/07 10:45:17 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
> [2023-02-07T15:45:18.5377868Z] [DESKTOP-H37P8Q0] [Info] [ConfigurationService] Using port 50256 for connection.
> [2023-02-07T15:45:18.5490854Z] [DESKTOP-H37P8Q0] [Info] [JvmBridge] JvMBridge port is 50256
> [2023-02-07T15:45:18.5529043Z] [DESKTOP-H37P8Q0] [Info] [JvmBridge] The number of JVM backend thread is set to 10. The max number of concurrent sockets in JvmBridge is set to 7.
> +----+----+----+----+
> |name|posX|posY|rate|
> +----+----+----+----+
> A| 100| -20|  20|
> B| 400|  30|  45|
> C| -10|  75|  61|
> D| 100| 120|  76|
> E|  48|  96|  88|
> F| 808|  46|  55|
> G|1200|  91|  99|
> +----+----+----+----+
> 
> +-------------+
> names|
> +-------------+
> |A|B|C|D|E|F|G|
> |A|B|C|D|E|G|F|
> |A|B|C|D|F|E|G|
> |A|B|C|D|F|G|E|
> |A|B|C|D|G|E|F|
> |A|B|C|D|G|F|E|
> |A|B|C|E|D|F|G|
> |A|B|C|E|D|G|F|
> |A|B|C|E|F|D|G|
> |A|B|C|E|F|G|D|
> |A|B|C|E|G|D|F|
> |A|B|C|E|G|F|D|
> |A|B|C|F|D|E|G|
> |A|B|C|F|D|G|E|
> |A|B|C|F|E|D|G|
> |A|B|C|F|E|G|D|
> |A|B|C|F|G|D|E|
> |A|B|C|F|G|E|D|
> |A|B|C|G|D|E|F|
> |A|B|C|G|D|F|E|
> +-------------+
> only showing top 20 rows
> 
> +-------------+--------------------+
> names|             players|
> +-------------+--------------------+
> |A|B|C|D|E|F|G|A,100,-20,20|B,40...|
> |A|B|C|D|E|G|F|A,100,-20,20|B,40...|
> |A|B|C|D|F|E|G|A,100,-20,20|B,40...|
> |A|B|C|D|F|G|E|A,100,-20,20|B,40...|
> |A|B|C|D|G|E|F|A,100,-20,20|B,40...|
> |A|B|C|D|G|F|E|A,100,-20,20|B,40...|
> |A|B|C|E|D|F|G|A,100,-20,20|B,40...|
> |A|B|C|E|D|G|F|A,100,-20,20|B,40...|
> |A|B|C|E|F|D|G|A,100,-20,20|B,40...|
> |A|B|C|E|F|G|D|A,100,-20,20|B,40...|
> |A|B|C|E|G|D|F|A,100,-20,20|B,40...|
> |A|B|C|E|G|F|D|A,100,-20,20|B,40...|
> |A|B|C|F|D|E|G|A,100,-20,20|B,40...|
> |A|B|C|F|D|G|E|A,100,-20,20|B,40...|
> |A|B|C|F|E|D|G|A,100,-20,20|B,40...|
> |A|B|C|F|E|G|D|A,100,-20,20|B,40...|
> |A|B|C|F|G|D|E|A,100,-20,20|B,40...|
> |A|B|C|F|G|E|D|A,100,-20,20|B,40...|
> |A|B|C|G|D|E|F|A,100,-20,20|B,40...|
> |A|B|C|G|D|F|E|A,100,-20,20|B,40...|
> +-------------+--------------------+
> only showing top 20 rows
> 
> [2023-02-07T15:45:30.2938453Z] [DESKTOP-H37P8Q0] [Debug] [ConfigurationService] Using the DOTNET_WORKER_DIR environment variable to construct .NET worker path: C:\bin\Microsoft.Spark.Worker-2.1.1\Microsoft.Spark.Worker.exe.
> DotnetWorker PID:[3636] Args:[-m pyspark.worker] SparkVersion:[2.4.5]
> [2023-02-07T15:45:31.0778526Z] [DESKTOP-H37P8Q0] [Info] [SimpleWorker] RunSimpleWorker() is starting with port = 50281.
> [2023-02-07T15:45:31.1251548Z] [DESKTOP-H37P8Q0] [Info] [TaskRunner] [0] Starting with ReuseSocket[False].
> [2023-02-07T15:45:31.1560166Z] [DESKTOP-H37P8Q0] [Info] [ConfigurationService] 'DOTNETBACKEND_PORT' environment variable is not set.
> [2023-02-07T15:45:31.1560166Z] [DESKTOP-H37P8Q0] [Info] [ConfigurationService] Using port 5567 for connection.
> [2023-02-07T15:45:31.1719795Z] [DESKTOP-H37P8Q0] [Info] [JvmBridge] JvMBridge port is 5567
> [2023-02-07T15:45:31.1719795Z] [DESKTOP-H37P8Q0] [Info] [JvmBridge] The number of JVM backend thread is set to 10. The max number of concurrent sockets in JvmBridge is set to 7.
> [2023-02-07T15:45:31.2810367Z] [DESKTOP-H37P8Q0] [Warn] [AssemblyLoader] Assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' file not found 'System.Private.CoreLib[.dll,.exe,.ni.dll,.ni.exe]' in 'C:\TestSparkApp\bin\Debug\net6.0,C:\Users\dtaylor\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-70f58a5a-d0d9-4cc7-b6c1-5d17da493edf\userFiles-432f5bf3-f3c2-4afa-a6ba-d3a6ce4a9e4e,C:\TestSparkApp,C:\bin\Microsoft.Spark.Worker-2.1.1\'
> [2023-02-07T15:45:31.2810367Z] [DESKTOP-H37P8Q0] [Warn] [AssemblyLoader] Assembly 'System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' file not found 'System.Private.CoreLib[.dll,.exe,.ni.dll,.ni.exe]' in 'C:\TestSparkApp\bin\Debug\net6.0,C:\Users\dtaylor\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-70f58a5a-d0d9-4cc7-b6c1-5d17da493edf\userFiles-432f5bf3-f3c2-4afa-a6ba-d3a6ce4a9e4e,C:\TestSparkApp,C:\bin\Microsoft.Spark.Worker-2.1.1\'
> [2023-02-07T15:45:31.3903664Z] [DESKTOP-H37P8Q0] [Error] [TaskRunner] [0] ProcessStream() failed with exception: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
> Parameter name: type
> at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
> at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
> at Microsoft.Spark.Utils.CommandSerDe.CreateUdfWrapperDelegate[T](Type type, Object[] parameters)
> at Microsoft.Spark.Utils.CommandSerDe.Deserialize[T](Stream stream, SerializedMode& serializerMode, SerializedMode& deserializerMode, String& runMode)
> at Microsoft.Spark.Worker.Processor.CommandProcessor.ReadSqlCommands(PythonEvalType evalType, Stream stream)
> at Microsoft.Spark.Worker.Processor.CommandProcessor.ReadSqlCommands(PythonEvalType evalType, Stream stream, Version version)
> at Microsoft.Spark.Worker.Processor.CommandProcessor.Process(Stream stream)
> at Microsoft.Spark.Worker.Processor.PayloadProcessor.Process(Stream stream)
> at Microsoft.Spark.Worker.TaskRunner.ProcessStream(Stream inputStream, Stream outputStream, Version version, Boolean& readComplete)
> removed for brevity
```

If I comment out the Show command the error is not thrown.  The error message specifies that argument named "type" is null and this argument is for a function called ProcessStream().  It looks like error comes out of TaskRunner.

**EDIT:**

It turns out that this error popups up on many DataFrame method calls but only after adding a column with WithColumn().

Does anyone else have this issue?

**EDIT:**

I's been a week with no response whatsoever.  Should I take that to mean that .NET for Apache Spark is no longer a viable product?  Should I abandon it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation of Spark .Net, the names of the types provided to the ‘Cast’ method should start with a lower case character, in your case you may try ‘int’ instead of ‘Integer’.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.spark.sql.column.cast?view=spark-dotnet

Comment: Eric,  Wow, thanks.  So simple.  I was worried that no one was involved with this product anymore.  Thanks so much.